# Changing the default for indexing from two columns to one, and getting rid of default page break

Tags: page-breaking, indexing, columns, blank-page

I need to create a table of cases for my thesis in international law and I'm using imakidx. Cases decided by international tribunals have long names and numbers as part of their citation, so if I have two columns, which is the default for indexing, the output is messy and becomes near impossible to read.[image]

Because I need to create several lists of cases, with sub-categories, I'm using a work-around, and instead of using splitindex, I'm just getting it to print each index separately. (Maybe not so elegant, and if there's a better alternative I would love to hear it. I'm a bit of a newbie with Latex and I'm a lawyer!):

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc,a4paper,openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=oscola, indexing=cite]{biblatex} %oscola is the legal 
citation package
\addbibresource{testingbiblio.bib} %necessary for Oscola
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes} %necessary for Oscola

\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=ICTY, title={International Criminal Tribunal for Former Yugoslavia}]
\makeindex[name=ICC, title={International Criminal Court}]
\makeindex[name=ca, title={Canada}]

\begin{document}


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\footcite{Vaillancourt}
Phasellus eget elit gravida, pharetra mauris at, malesuada dui. Sed vitae tortor ante. 
Quisque sollicitudin accumsan nulla sit amet mattis.\footcite{Tadic} Nam non malesuada 
nisl. Aliquam erat volutpat.\footcites{Vasiljevic}{Banda} In eu vulputate sem, in 
sagittis arcu. Nullam fringilla libero non nisi aliquam, eget pulvinar arcu pulvinar. 
Ut tristique ullamcorper nisl, vitae cursus nulla varius vel. Proin non rhoncus 
risus.\footcite{AlBashirIndictment}


\chapter*{Table of Cases}
\section*{International Tribunals}
\printindex[ICTY]
\printindex[ICC]

\section*{Domestic Tribunals}
\printindex[ca]


\end{document}
```

The problem I have now is the automatic page break in between my \chapter* command and the index, and in between each index. How do I get rid of these default page breaks? And also, how do I change the default of two columns to one column, so that the case citations are readable?

I would like the final output to look something like this:
[image]

Here is my basis bib file:

```
@jurisdiction{AlBashirIndictment,
title = {Public Redacted Version of Prosecutor's Application for Warrant of Arrest 
under Art. 58},
shorttitle = {Al Bashir Application for Warrant of Arrest},
date = {2008-09-12},
number = {ICC-02/05-157},
court = {Pre Trial Chamber},
pagination = {paragraph},
tabulate= {ICC},
keywords={ICC}
}

@jurisdiction{Banda,
title = {The Prosecutor v Banda and Jerbo, Corrigendum of the Decision on the 
Confirmation of Charges},
shorttitle = {Banda Decision on Charges Corrigendum},
date = {2011-03-07},
number = {ICC--02/05-03/09-121-Conf-Corr},
court = {Pre Trial Chamber},
pagination = {paragraph},
tabulate = {ICC},
keywords={ICC}
}

@jurisdiction{Tadic,
title = {The Prosecutor v Dusko Tadi\'{c}, Appeals Judgment},
shorttitle = {Tadi\'{c} Appeals Judgment},
date = {1999-07-15},
number = {IT-94-1-A},
court = {Appeals Chamber},
pagination = {paragraph},
tabulate= {ICTY},
keywords={ICTY}
}

@jurisdiction{Vasiljevic,
title = {The Prosecutor v Mitar Vasiljevi\'{c}, Appeals Judgment},
shorttitle = {Vasiljevi\'{c} Appeal},
date = {2004-02-25},
number = {IT-98-32-A},
court = {Appeals Chamber},
pagination = {paragraph},
tabulate = {ICTY},
keywords={ICTY}
}

@jurisdiction{Vaillancourt,
title = {R. v Vaillancourt},
shorttitle = {Vaillancourt},
date = {1987},
court = {Supreme Court of Canada},
reporter = {S.C.R.},
volume = {2},
pages = {636},
pagination = {paragraph},
location = {Canada},
keywords = {ca}
```

}

Comment: It is not clear what you want. What is the relation between your question and `bib` files?

Comment: @Sigur - Sorry for not being clear. My bib file is just to show the information that is complied for a case citation in the index. What I want to know is how to create an index with categories and sub-categories as shown in my example, without page breaks in between each index, and without the default two columns (single column would make the case citations readable).

Answer (score 5):

Add the `columns=1` option to the index definition command:

```
\makeindex[
  name=ICC,
  columns=1,
  title={International Criminal Court}
]
```

[image]